# Does Prototype has a no conflict option like jQuery?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have tried Googling this but it only ever comes up with the jQuery noconflict option.

I would use this but my site is very jQuery heavy and it will take quite a white, as well as this the prototype code I'm adding may be temporary and is only a few lines.

If there is no prototype no conflict option how would I convert the below code, my javascript codes are limited?

```
// JavaScript Document
// calculate price based on quantity
function changeQty(change){
var currentQty = parseInt($F('quant')) // Where quant is the id of your quantity input field. Gets value of currentQty field

switch (change) {
    case 'add':
        currentQty += 1
        $('quant').value = currentQty
        calculate()
        break
    case 'subtract':
        if (currentQty > 1) { // only subtract if qty is greater than zero
            currentQty -= 1
            $('quant').value = currentQty
            calculate()
        }
        break
    case 'field':
        if (currentQty > 0) {
            window.setTimeout('calculate()', 500)
        }
        break
}
}
function calculate(){
var currentQty = parseInt($F('quant')) // Where quant is the id of your quantity input field. Gets value of currentQty field    
var jsnormalprice = $F('jsnormalprice') // Where jsnormalprice is the id of your hidden base price field. Gets value of base_price field    
var jsspecialprice = $F('jsspecialprice') // Where  is the id of your hidden base price field. Gets value of base_price field   

if (currentQty > 0) { // Don't want price to display if zero if customer zeros out quantity
    var new_jsnormalprice = jsnormalprice * currentQty // Calculate the price.      
    var new_jsnormalprice = new_jsnormalprice.toFixed(2) // Only allow 2 decimals. I'll let you add rounding features up or down.

    var new_jsspecialprice = jsspecialprice * currentQty // Calculate the price.        
    var new_jsspecialprice = new_jsspecialprice.toFixed(2) // Only allow 2 decimals. I'll let you add rounding features up or down.

} else { // set price back to original price
    new_jsnormalprice = jsnormalprice
    new_jsspecialprice = jsspecialprice
}   

$('jsnormalpriceshow').update(new_jsnormalprice) // Where jsnormalpriceshow is the id of your span for the echoed product price
$('jsspecialpriceshow').update(new_jsspecialprice) // Where jsspecialpriceshow is the id of your span for the echoed product price

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prototype does not have a no conflict mode...

I've converted your code, but I may have missed a spot or two...

Generally, `$('elemID')` => `$('#elemID')` and `$F('elemID')` => `$('#elemID').val()` is what I've done..

```
// JavaScript Document
// calculate price based on quantity
function changeQty(change){
var currentQty = parseInt($('#quant').val()) // Where quant is the id of your quantity input field. Gets value of currentQty field

switch (change) {
    case 'add':
        currentQty += 1
        $('#quant').val(currentQty)
        calculate()
        break
    case 'subtract':
        if (currentQty > 1) { // only subtract if qty is greater than zero
            currentQty -= 1
            $('#quant').val(currentQty)
            calculate()
        }
        break
    case 'field':
        if (currentQty > 0) {
            window.setTimeout('calculate()', 500)
        }
        break
}
}
function calculate(){
var currentQty = parseInt($('#quant').val()) // Where quant is the id of your quantity input field. Gets value of currentQty field    
var jsnormalprice = $('#jsnormalprice').val() // Where jsnormalprice is the id of your hidden base price field. Gets value of base_price field    
var jsspecialprice = $('#jsspecialprice').val() // Where  is the id of your hidden base price field. Gets value of base_price field   

if (currentQty > 0) { // Don't want price to display if zero if customer zeros out quantity
    var new_jsnormalprice = jsnormalprice * currentQty // Calculate the price.      
    var new_jsnormalprice = new_jsnormalprice.toFixed(2) // Only allow 2 decimals. I'll let you add rounding features up or down.

    var new_jsspecialprice = jsspecialprice * currentQty // Calculate the price.        
    var new_jsspecialprice = new_jsspecialprice.toFixed(2) // Only allow 2 decimals. I'll let you add rounding features up or down.

} else { // set price back to original price
    new_jsnormalprice = jsnormalprice
    new_jsspecialprice = jsspecialprice
}   

$('#jsnormalpriceshow').html(new_jsnormalprice) // Where jsnormalpriceshow is the id of your span for the echoed product price
$('#jsspecialpriceshow').html(new_jsspecialprice) // Where jsspecialpriceshow is the id of your span for the echoed product price

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Prototype does not have a no conflict mode.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, prototype does not have a no conflict mode.

Fortunately, you do not need to use Prototype to select elements in the DOM. jQuery works perfectly fine for that.

Instead of

```
$F('quant')
$('quant').value = currentQty
$F('jsnormalprice')
$('jsnormalpriceshow').update(new_jsnormalprice)
```

You can use the jQuery equivalents:

```
$("#quant").val()
$("#quant").val(currentQty)
$("#jsnormalprice").val()
$("#jsnormalpriceshow").text(new_jsnormalprice)
```

---

And, please, don't evaluate code in a string. Change

```
window.setTimeout('calculate()', 500)
```

to the more natural way of doing it:

```
window.setTimeout(calculate, 500)
```