# How to change the name of the '$' function on Prototype JS library?

Tags: jquery, prototype

I am using both jQuery and Prototype libraries in my application (forced to that because of 3rd party plugins).

Both libraries use the '$' as their core function.
I know how to change the $ on jQuery to something else to avoid a conflict.
However I prefer to change the Prototype $ function, as most of my code uses jQuery.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Prototype has a no conflict option like jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555794/does-prototype-has-a-no-conflict-option-like-jquery)

Comment: @undefined: It is a near dup, since the on the other question, the OP has little dependence on Prototype, the solution over there is to not use Prototype at all.

Answer (score 4):

Has any one tried something like this after both libraries have loaded?

```
<script>
// using Prototype.js
Event.observe(window, 'load', function () {
    window._ = window.$;    // assign $ to _
    window.$ = jQuery;      // re-assign $ to jQuery
});
// or using jQuery
/*
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    window._ = window.$;    // assign $ to _
    window.$ = jQuery;      // re-assign $ to jQuery
});
*/
</script>
```

This should put Prototype.js on `_` and jQuery on `$`.

Failing that, this [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) pattern should allow you to use $ for jQuery (and for Prototype):

```
<script>
// do Prototype.js stuff using $
(function ($) {
    $('#myElem').addClassName('hidden').insert('Prototype added class "hidden" so now you cannot see me!);
}(window.$));

// do jQuery things using $
(function ($) {
    $('#myElem').removeClass('hidden').append($('<p />').text('jQuery removed class "hidden" so now you can see me!));
}(jQuery.noConflict()));
</script>
```

Comment: What's the point of asking jQuery to restore $ to something else, then overwriting $ anyways?

Comment: @JanDvorak: The point is to use either Prototype (`Event`) or `jQuery` to assign the `$` to jQuery after assigning Prototype to another variable (`_` in this case). Re-edited comments in answer for [hopefully] better clarity.

Comment: My point is that all `.noConflict` does is that it assigns to `$` and returns `jQuery`. `$ = jQuery.noConflict` is equivalent to `$ = jQuery`.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Ah, I see now. Edited answer. (Sorry! Long day.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use non-conflict in jQuery.

Then change the $ to something else. Then you can change $ to jQuery.

```
$p = $;
$ = jQuery;
```